# Meteor with cloud9

Tags: meteor, cloud9-ide

When trying to run meteor in cloud9 I encounter one of the following errors:

Running the older [modified version from cloud9](https://github.com/c9/meteor) I get the error:

```
No dependency info in bundle. Filesystem monitoring disabled.
=> Errors prevented startup:
Exception while bundling application:
Error: Package not found: standard-app-packages
    at self.api.use (/var/lib/stickshift/532a1c97500446885f0002a8/app-root/data/meteor/tools/bundler.js:113:17)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/var/lib/stickshift/532a1c97500446885f0002a8/app-root/data/meteor/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at Object.self.api.use (/var/lib/stickshift/532a1c97500446885f0002a8/app-root/data/meteor/tools/bundler.js:110:9)
```

When I try running the [lastest version](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/master), I get an error from cloud9:

```
Cloud9  Error: you may be using the wrong PORT & HOST for your server app
        Node: use 'process.env.PORT' as the port and 'process.env.IP' as the host in your scripts. See also https://c9.io/site/blog/2013/05/can-i-use-cloud9-to-do-x/
```

In both cases, I clone the corresponding GitHub repository and run `export BIND_IP=$IP` as well as `export PORT=20000` (as it is described in on several posts). I also gave up the hope using the default MongoDB server and am instead exporting `MONGO_URL` to a free database hosted on https://www.mongohq.com/.

I've also tried to merge the pull request from cloud9's meteor version to the master, but those files don't even exist anymore. Everything else I could find was about Meteor version 0.6.5 and 0.5

Trying to modify the latest Meteor-version I looked for the `httpServer.listen` call, but I found only one in `meteor/packages/webapp/webapp_server.js`, and it seems that the cloud9 error is thrown before that part of code is reached (if it is ever reached). So that there must be a another piece of code which is bound to the wrong address or port.

The plugins I use are:

```
standard-app-packages
insecure
preserve-inputs
underscore
backbone
jquery
accounts-ui
accounts-base
accounts-password
accounts-facebook
accounts-google
coffeescript
```

---

**Update:**

After some more hours looking for a solution, I got much further. The problem was in [meteor/tools/run-proxy.js](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/7318071327697078ae8728fabfa1de2f1852287c/tools/run-proxy.js):

In line 94 you can see: `self.server.listen(self.listenPort, function () {` here is the corresponding IP-address missing to which the server should bind itself. Now meteor used to use an environmental variable `BIND_IP` which we could introduce here again, but this would have unnecessary additional changes on cloud9, since they export the current IP address to which a service should bind itself in the `IP` variable. So I changed the line in question to: `self.server.listen(self.listenPort, process.env.IP, function () {`

I've also additionally modified [meteor/tools/run-all.js](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/7318071327697078ae8728fabfa1de2f1852287c/tools/run-all.js), since I wasn't sure if the correct port parameter is used. On line 24 I exchanged `var listenPort = options.port;` with `var listenPort = process.env.PORT;`

While I can now finally start the application, it is still not running and I'm getting the following output:

```
=> Running Meteor from a checkout -- overrides project version (0.7.2)
[[[[[ ~/<PROJECT_ID>/<PROJECT_NAME> ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
W20140321-22:31:42.591(-4)? (STDERR) 
W20140321-22:31:43.036(-4)? (STDERR) events.js:72
W20140321-22:31:43.037(-4)? (STDERR)         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
W20140321-22:31:43.037(-4)? (STDERR)               ^


 Cloud9  Error: you may be using the wrong PORT & HOST for your server app
         Node: use 'process.env.PORT' as the port and 'process.env.IP' as the host in your scripts. See also https://c9.io/site/blog/2013/05/can-i-use-cloud9-to-do-x/
W20140321-22:31:43.108(-4)? (STDERR) Error: listen EACCES
W20140321-22:31:43.109(-4)? (STDERR)     at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
W20140321-22:31:43.109(-4)? (STDERR)     at Server._listen2 (net.js:1020:19)
W20140321-22:31:43.111(-4)? (STDERR)     at listen (net.js:1061:10)
W20140321-22:31:43.111(-4)? (STDERR)     at net.js:1143:9
W20140321-22:31:43.112(-4)? (STDERR)     at dns.js:72:18
W20140321-22:31:43.112(-4)? (STDERR)     at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
=> Exited with code: 8
```

However meteor doesn't crash and the exceptions keep coming in one after another. That's why I first thought, the exception is due to an authentication error on MongoDB, since also Error-Code 8 for MongoDB is authentication error, but this is what I get when I use an invalid username + password on my MongoHQ-hosted database:

```
[...]
=> Started proxy.
W20140321-22:54:17.282(-4)? (STDERR) 
W20140321-22:54:18.700(-4)? (STDERR) /var/lib/stickshift/532a1c97500446885f0002a8/app-root/data/meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/.build/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/mongo_client.js:400
W20140321-22:54:18.777(-4)? (STDERR)               throw err
W20140321-22:54:18.778(-4)? (STDERR)                     ^
W20140321-22:54:18.778(-4)? (STDERR) MongoError: auth fails
W20140321-22:54:18.778(-4)? (STDERR)     at Object.toError (/var/lib/stickshift/532a1c97500446885f0002a8/app-root/data/meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/.build/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/utils.js:110:11)
W20140321-22:54:18.779(-4)? (STDERR)     at /var/lib/stickshift/532a1c97500446885f0002a8/app-root/data/meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/.build/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/auth/mongodb_cr.js:34:33
W20140321-22:54:18.779(-4)? (STDERR)     at /var/lib/stickshift/532a1c97500446885f0002a8/app-root/data/meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/.build/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1670:9
W20140321-22:54:18.779(-4)? (STDERR)     at Server.Base._callHandler (/var/lib/stickshift/532a1c97500446885f0002a8/app-root/data/meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/.build/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:382:41)
W20140321-22:54:18.780(-4)? (STDERR)     at /var/lib/stickshift/532a1c97500446885f0002a8/app-root/data/meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/.build/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:472:18
W20140321-22:54:18.780(-4)? (STDERR)     at MongoReply.parseBody (/var/lib/stickshift/532a1c97500446885f0002a8/app-root/data/meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/.build/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/responses/mongo_reply.js:68:5)
W20140321-22:54:18.780(-4)? (STDERR)     at null.<anonymous> (/var/lib/stickshift/532a1c97500446885f0002a8/app-root/data/meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/.build/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:430:20)
W20140321-22:54:18.781(-4)? (STDERR)     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
W20140321-22:54:18.781(-4)? (STDERR)     at null.<anonymous> (/var/lib/stickshift/532a1c97500446885f0002a8/app-root/data/meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/.build/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:191:13)
W20140321-22:54:18.782(-4)? (STDERR)     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
=> Exited with code: 8
```

This error is thrown in [meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/5486fd0b337bdcfdb1b8e63dc34dce33e5e4d123/packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js) at line 149:

```
147:      MongoDB.connect(url, mongoOptions, function(err, db) {
148:        if (err)
149:          throw err;
150:        self.db = db;
```

This is also OK, however I couldn't find where the other error comes from, which occurs, when my credentials are correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just ran into similar issues initially, but the latest version of Meteor (0.9.0) makes this easy at least.

```
meteor run --port=$IP:$PORT
```

Seems to do the trick (at least so far)

This is doc'd in

```
meteor help run
```

hth

Andy

Comment: Yeah, it was obviously a bug in the old version, so I'm happy to see that they fixed it now

Comment: Currently its without "equal" sign:
meteor run --port $IP:$PORT

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so actually the first part of the question is the correct answer, if I hadn't done it the other way around:

`BIND_IP` is used within [meteor/packages/webapp/webapp_server.js](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/webapp/webapp_server.js), but not in [meteor/tools/run-proxy.js](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/7318071327697078ae8728fabfa1de2f1852287c/tools/run-proxy.js). However both need to bind to cloud9's 'IP'-variable.

So to solve this issue, simply update the proxy, similar as I did it, to use the correct IP-address: `self.server.listen(self.listenPort, process.env.IP, function () {`

and just write in your .bashrc `export BIND_IP=$IP`

now everything works smoothly (provided, that you use a mongodb outside of cloud9)

I've summarised the necessary steps in my blog: http://peter.grman.at/how-to-run-meteor-in-cloud9/

Answer (score 1):

meteor works very nice in c9.io, i am working in c9.io with metor. just following the steps.

> 1. select workshop as nodejs.
> 2. in terminal write the command "curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh"
> 3. in terminal write $ meteor create newapp(your main application folder name)
> 4. in terminal write cd newapp
> 5. in terminal write $ meteor -p 8080 (note -p or --port, if you using port as 300 that not working properly in c9.io . so you should using port as 8080 or 8081 or 8082)
> 6. after few seconds you get a link  app running at: localhost:8080
> 7. click the link and open it.

Answer (score 0):

**Meteor 1.4:**

At first, I tried a lot of different variations, with and without the `--port` flag mentioned in Andrew's answer.

- If I only ran the `meteor` command without any flag, the app would successfully start on port 3000, but apparently that port can't be used in Cloud9 (https://docs.c9.io/docs/multiple-ports)
- If I used the `--port` flag, meteor would just hang on "Starting your app"

Most likely something got stuck along the way (with all the retries), because what probably finally fixed it was to run a `meteor reset` before starting the app ([Meteor application - Stuck at "Starting your app" when trying to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36649478/meteor-application-stuck-at-starting-your-app-when-trying-to-run)):

```
...$ sudo meteor reset
...$ sudo meteor --port=$IP:$PORT
```

If that doesn't help, I had also added some detailed logging on the attempt that finally worked (see this meteor forum post: [Meteor stuck at starting your app](https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-stuck-at-starting-your-app/25592/7)). Try this if you're still stuck:

```
...$ sudo meteor reset
...$ METEOR_PROFILE=1
...$ METEOR_LOG=debug
...$ sudo meteor --port=$IP:$PORT --verbose
```

After it worked the first time, I can now start the app with only one command:

```
...$ sudo meteor --port=$IP:$PORT
```