# Meteor command not running c9

Tags: meteor, cloud9, c9.io

I have cloned the meteor repository from github to c9. But when I type meteor in the console it reads -- bash: meteor: command not found.

Comment: Cloud9 have canned Meteor machine, you need to create a new workspace from that template, not simply a Node workspace. Anyway, what you should do is to install Meteor. Simply follow the "curl ... | sh" example from https://meteor.com.

Comment: @RishatMuhametshin - The meteor template doesn't exist anymore: https://community.c9.io/t/meteor-workspace-type-not-listed-when-i-create-a-new-workspace/6128/6  The default install procedure is the way to go (as you also mention).

Answer (score 1):

You should "Create a new workspace" that clone from `https://github.com/meteor/meteor.git`.

After it's completed, using curl `https://install.meteor.com/ | sh`.

You could run your project by `meteor run --port=$IP:$PORT` if you have a problem about PORT and IP.

P/s: I solved it by this way!

#Source: [Meteor with cloud9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22561328/meteor-with-cloud9/)