# Create a Meteor App on Cloud9

Tags: meteor, cloud9-ide

[Cloud9](https://c9.io) is the only online IDE recommended for Meteor in [meteor.com](https://www.meteor.com/developers). But the  '[two clicks to awesome](https://c9.io/blog/two-clicks-to-awesome-meteor-workspace/)' guide is not applicable, because Meteor is not listed in workspace types any more. What's the best way to create a Meteor app on Cloud9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested  the following procedure and it works:

1. Go to https://c9.io/new and create a Blank workspace.
2. Run `curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh` in command line to install Meteor.
3. Run `meteor create my_cool_app`. (Don't put `~/` before the app name.)
4. Run `cd/my_app`
5. Run `meteor --port $IP:$PORT` to start the sample app. (Without `$IP:$PORT` it hangs). Make sure the app is working.
6. If you want to upload your app to the new directory, delete all files and folders in my_app directory.
7. Click on my_app name on the right pane. Then in the "File" menu, click on upload files.
8. Make sure you have a list of packages that needs to be installed. You can use `meteor list` on your previous working directory.
9. First use `meteor add` and `meteor remove` commands to add/remove the MDG packages. If you install 3rd party packages first, you'll get weird errors.
10. Add 3rd part packages.
11. Run `meteor --port $IP:$PORT` to start your app. The first time it may take a few minutes to start the app but later it'll be a few seconds.

Comment: New meteor versions seem quite big. I used Meteor template on a free account before and now coming back I cannot use my app as it installs an update automatically and it fills all the disk space and the app does not work. MongoDB Crashes as out of space. Even using this tutorial from a blank template does not work. Only premiums seem now able to get meteor working on C9. That might be the reason why they removed as an option on the templates (free accounts).

Comment: C9 free account is sufficient for developing meteor apps with a few thousands of  LOC and a few tens of MB of data.

Answer (score 2):

It definitely can be done!

First you're going to create a blank workspace environment in Cloud9

[image: Create a blank environment]

Second you're going to install meteor with

```
curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
```

[image: Install Meteor]

Then just create your project and run with Meteor!

[image: Run with Meteor!]

Comment: When I select "run with Meteor" from menu I get an error "You're not in a Meteor project directory." though I am in its directory.

Comment: Can you send a screenshot?

Comment: it's a known issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22561328/meteor-with-cloud9?rq=1

Comment: Can you send a screenshot of your file structure? I'm curious about something

Answer (score 1):

Install Meteor after creating new workspace.

```
username:~/workspace $ curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
```

Create new app my-app.This will create a blank app.

```
username:~/workspace $ meteor create my-app
```

Change current directory to created app.

```
username:~/workspace $ cd app-name
```

Install node packages required for meteor app.

```
username:~/workspace/app-name $ meteor npm install
```

Run you meteor app using port option.

```
username:~/workspace/app-name $ meteor --port $IP:$PORT
```

First time it takes around 15 minutes to get up and running. After that it will run quickly every time. You need to use --port option specifically for Cloud9 as it does not support automatic ports.